# visibility:hidden in firefox how to?

Tags: css, firefox, visibility

I have code like this:

```
.module::first-letter{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

But this solution is not working on Firefox:(
Display:none; not working with "::first-letter" CSS code :(

How can I hide first letter in Firefox?

Comment: The property  `visibility` is no available on this selector.. you can color the letter with the same color as the background

Comment: OK I used: font-size:0px; :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always try setting `font-size:0` while this is not fully supported.

```css
.module::first-letter{
    font-size:0
}
```

```html
<div class="module">Hide Letter H  </div>
```

or as last resort `color:transparent`

```css
.module::first-letter {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<div class="module">Hide Letter H</div>
```

***Note the difference between both, 1st removes the letter space, second
one doesn't.***

Answer (score 1):

Note: The following properties can be used with ::first-letter:

- font properties
- color properties
- background properties
- margin properties
- padding properties
- border properties
- text-decoration
- vertical-align (only if float is 'none')
- text-transform
- line-height
- float
- clear

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstletter.asp

Another note, it only works with block level elements, I am not sure, and I could be wrong, you can hide the first letter with only CSS. Quite easy in JS to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers the properties that can are used is limited but it's possible other browser vendors are initiating greater support

> As this list will be extended in the future, it is recommended that you not use any other properties inside the declaration block, in order to keep the CSS future-proof.

Source: [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter)

Comment: Not in firefox...chrome is cheating ;)

Comment: hmmm... there is no <p> tag in code... it is text in <td>text here</td> and this CSS code not working there:/ I can't modify html code, I have only CSS to edit.

Comment: Hmmm...I had this working in FF a minute ago..and it's stopped...Oh well,

Comment: OK i made it this way: font-size:0px; :D